# directX exporter not exporting animation

Tags: animation, export, file-format

How to reproduce:

1. Open blender 2.72, with default cube scene
2. 'n' to open properties panel and switch rotation to Quaternion wxyz
3. press 'i' , Rotation - to save rotation at keyframe 1
4. move to keyframe 30 (right arrow key)
5. rotate about x axis 90 ( 'r', 'x', 90, enter )
6. 'i' to save rotation key
7. export .x file
8. edit .x file and see rotations, all keys are the same ? thats a problem!

Can someone atleast confirm this?

Comment: I have fixed this on my end by replacing line 1050 with :
Rotation = BlenderObject.matrix_local.to_quaternion() and redoing the animation.
,but this is a temporary fix, as it will output zeros if anim angles are in Euler.

Comment: Thanks that you provided a workaround for this issue, please understand that we will close this question because it seems to be a bug report.

Comment: Yes, no problem.